# How to get all content by performing group_by - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working in codeigniter my problem is i have a query in which i am performing group_by('content_id'), i need to display all the content of same content_id seperately but its showing content of only first row of that group.
Pls help.

Below is my Model

```
public function get_content(){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('content');
        $this->db->order_by('content_id', 'ASC');
        $this->db->group_by('content_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: As per the documentation of CI, you need foreach to loop the results.

Comment: Did you tried this query within your sql what's the result for particular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) is what you need.

```
$this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(column_name separator ", ") as alias',FALSE) // FALSE to protect the backticks
```